# How do I get the right index of the string character?

Tags: c++, arrays

Write a function receives a string and a character which is to be searched in the string. This function function returns the index of the search character if it exists in the array, or -1 if it does not. Also if the array contains more than one occurrence of the character, it returns the index of the left-most occurrence. For instance, if the string was ”abab” and the search character was ’b’, the function returns 1; whereas if the character was ’c’, the function returns -1.
Write the function WITHOUT using any C++ library functions.

Below is my function.

```
int indexOf(const char str[], char ch)
{
    int search;
    for (int i = 0; i<20; i++)
    {
        if (ch = str[i])
            search ==i;
        else
            search =-1;

    }
    return search;
}
```

My problem is I keep getting 19(20-1) when I input either the search character or the character that doesn't exist in the array. Could anyone tell me how to modify my code to get the right answer?

Comment: change `if (ch = str[i])` to `if (ch == str[i])` and `search ==i;` to `search =i;`... your compiler should have emitted a warning...

Comment: You should pass the capacity of the array, rather than assuming (hard coding) the capacity at 20.

Comment: Also, in the `if` statement, change `=` to `==`.  No need for an `else` clause here.

Comment: You should also added a `break` statement inside the `if` statement block.  This will exit the loop once the character is found.  By the requirements, the first match is the winner.

Comment: By the way, why did you tag the question C++ when everything smells to C?

Answer (score 2):

`if (ch = str[i])` should be `if (ch == str[i])`, at the moment you're just doing an assignment to `ch`.

And `search ==i` is doing a comparison, it should be `search = i`; so it's the opposite issue of the first.

Comment: Just as I was typing in the extra bit :)

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is:

```
int indexOf(const char str[], int size, char ch)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == '\0')
            return -1;
        else if(str[i] == ch)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The approach has the advantage of not wasting time searching in the rest of the string when it was already discovered before.

Comment: I think, just one condition: if(str[i] == ch) return i; is enough inside for loop. Because, it should have a relation of size with '\0' of the string :)

Comment: Imagine the string is "10111213141516171819". When reaching the 9 at the end of the string, you still didn't get the '\0' character because the string hasn't space for it. So your loop will advance for a memory region it should not!

Answer (score 0):

You did some mistakes. **if (ch = str[i])** should be **if (ch == str[i])** and **search ==i;** should be **search =i;**

And, no need to use the size of the arr if you pass a null-terminated strings.

You can try like this.

```
int indexOf(const char str[], char ch)
{
    for (int idx = 0; str[idx]; idx++)
    {
        if (str[idx] == ch)
            return idx;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Your continuation condition `str[idx]` in the for loop is wrong! You will get an overflow if there isn't a '\0' character before the end of the string! That is why the size is needed!

Comment: Yes, the string should be null terminated. Thanks for pointing it out.